# ArgumentOutOfRangeException Constructor (String) definition

Tags: c#

I am just trying to get some more details about how Exceptions work. From MSDN page [ArgumentOutOfRangeException Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsw6yh2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I find the note: "This constructor initializes the ParamName property of the new instance using the paramName parameter. *The content of paramName is intended to be understood by humans.*"

What does this really mean? Is it obligatory for the string input of ArgumentException to always match the method definition input name?
(i.e. double amount --> "amount")

If it is obligatory, wouldn't be easier for maintenance purposes that the string should be automatically updated somehow if the method input arguments changed names?

From MSDN unitTesting tutorial we have the following code:

```
       public void Debit(double amount)
    {
        if (m_frozen)
        {
            throw new Exception("Account frozen");
        }

        if (amount > m_balance)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
          //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("whatever");  <-- this is my comment
          //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("what is the point?"); <-- this is my comment
        }

        if (amount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
        }

        m_balance -= amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this really mean?

This means that the parameter passed as the `paramName` *should be* the the actual parameter that caused the exception. Why? Because if an exception is thrown, that means your program encountered errorness behavior and it would help to know which param was out of its range.

> If it is obligatory, wouldn't be easier for maintenance purposes that the string should be automatically updated somehow if the method definition changed?

Yes, it definitely would. That is exactly why C# 6 introduced the [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx):

```
public void Foo(int amount)
{
     if (amount < balance)
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says. The content is supposed to be understood by the person reading it, not a machine. So, you should make it something that's descriptive to the problem (probably the *argument* that was *out of range*).

It's not "obligatory" for the `paramName` to match the actual name of the method parameter, but it will probably help those maintaining your code.

Comment: So if at some point the method's input argument's name change, the best practice for the maintainers is to update the Exception string also? Isn't it error prone?

Comment: It makes sense to update the string, and yes, that can be error prone. C# 6 added the `nameof` operator for this very purpose. You can use it as in `nameof(amount)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to simply and clearly answer your question, No it doesn't matter waht you pass as this argument. you just pass it here :

```
void SomeMethod(/*someParameters*/)
{
    ...
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("your desired name");
    ...
}
```

and use it as :

```
try
{
    ...
    SomeMethod(...);
    ...
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception)
{
    use exception.ParamName
}
```

you'd better pass the parameter name to realize which parameter was out of range 
in catch.
I hope it helps.